# Having difficulty retrieving data from useEffect hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm having some trouble with my useEffect hook that I just cannot seem to get it to work. I'm trying to make a call to this endpoint, however, I believe that I am getting nothing back.

I would really appreciate any help.(I've updated my X-RapidAPI-Key, so that it does not display here of course). My 'console.log(json)' appears to retrieve no results, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

I'm trying to follow the guidelines as per the website's advice here https://rapidapi.com/api-sports/api/api-football/

My code is as follows

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";  // Changed
import Header from "../components/headerTeamList";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TeamList from "../components/teamList";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    padding: "20px",
  },
});

const TeamListPage = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  console.log(teams)

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '**********************',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };

    fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings/?season=2021&league=39', options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        return json.response;
      })
      .then((teams) => {
        setTeams(teams);
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Header title={"Home Page"} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container spacing={5}>
        <TeamList teams={teams}></TeamList>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default TeamListPage;
```

Comment: Is the code actually running? I don't see " import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react' " at the top of the file.

Comment: Apologies, I have it in my code. I failed to add it here but have updated

Comment: Check devtools network tab, check the request and response to the api call.

Comment: I've taken a look at devtools and almost seems as if the call is not being made at all, but I can't understand why

Comment: In the console, I'm receiving error messages informing me, for example, 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'standings')', so it's trying to access the component, but doesn't appear to be making the api call

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's (at least) not helping you right now is that you don't have a `.catch` block, you can `console.log(response)` all day but if an error is occur and you don't `console.log(error)`, you won't know what went wrong and why. (that is if you are like me and debugging by console loggin lol)

Try this. at least it would tell you why its not working.

```
  fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings/?season=2021&league=39', options)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
      return json.response;
    })
    .then((teams) => {
      setTeams(teams);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

If you want to do `async.. await`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchFunction = async (url, opt) => {
    try {
      const reponse = await fetch(url, opt);
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      const data = await responseJson.response;
      setTeam(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    };
  };
  // remember to actually call it 
  fetchFunction('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings/?season=2021&league=39', options)
}, []);
```

Reminder that you cannot do `async.. await` on the top level with `useEffect`, hence why we gotta define a function and call it, it's silly, but it is what it is.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably getting lost inside in one of the multiple **.then**. Why don't you try something like this:

```
const OPTIONS = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '**********************',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };

const handleFetch = async () => {
 const response = await fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings/?season=2021&league=39', options);
const json = await response.json();

setTeams(json);

}

useEffect(() => {
 handleFetch();
}, [])
```